# Getting a rectangle to draw over text with tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

I am trying to make a Rock Paper Scissors game but i can not figure out how to draw a rectangle over the text.  This is my code:

```
class game:
    def __init__(self):
        self.choices = ['Rock','Paper','Scissors']
        self.final_human_score = 0
        self.final_computer_score = 0
        rock_b = Button(canvas,text="Rock",bg='black',fg='green',command=self.rock)
        rock_b.place(x=225,y=40)
        paper_b = Button(canvas,text="Paper",bg='black',fg='green',command=self.paper)
        paper_b.place(x=290,y=40)
        scissors_b = Button(canvas,text="Scissors",bg="black",fg='green',comman=self.scissors)
        scissors_b.place(x=360,y=40)
        self.human_turn = False
        self.computer_turn = True

    def turn(self):
        start_x = 75
        start_y = 100
        start_x2 = 90
        start_y2 =200
        Turn = canvas.create_rectangle(start_x,start_y,50,50,fill='green')
        not_turn = canvas.create_rectangle(start_x2,start_y2,50,50,fill='red')

    def rock(self):
        if self.human_turn == False:
            #280,90,400,113
            self.choice_display = canvas.create_text(310,100,text="Rock",fill="white",font=('Courier',13))
            global human_turn #global required to change human_turn and commputer_turn
            global computer_turn
            self.human_turn = True
            self.computer_turn = False
            self.cc()

    def paper(self):
        if self.human_turn == False:
            self.choice_display = canvas.create_text(315,100,text="Paper",fill="white",font=('Courier',13))
            global human_turn
            global computer_turn
            self.human_turn = True
            self.computer_turn = False
            self.cc()

    def scissors(self):
        if self.human_turn == False:
            self.choice_display = canvas.create_text(330,100,text="Scissors",fill="white",font=('Courier',13))
            global human_turn
            global computer_turn
            self.human_turn = True
            self.computer_turn = False
            self.cc()

    def cc(self): #(computer choice)
        computer_choice = random.choice(self.choices)
        if self.computer_turn == False:
            if computer_choice == 'Rock':
                self.c_choice_display = canvas.create_text(310,200,text="Rock",fill="white",font=("Courier",13))
                global human_turn
                global computer_turn
                self.human_turn = False
                self.computer_turn = True
            elif computer_choice == 'Paper':
                self.c_choice_display = canvas.create_text(315,200,text="Paper",fill="white",font=("Courier",13))
                global human_turn
                global computer_turn
                self.human_turn = False
                self.computer_turn = True
            elif computer_choice == 'Scissors':
                self.c_choice_display = canvas.create_text(330,200,text="Scissors",fill="white",font=("Courier",13))
                global human_turn
                global computer_turn
                self.human_turn = False
                self.computer_turn = True
```

In the game class, how would I make it wait 3 seconds and then cover up the computers choice and the humans choice?

Answer (score 0):

From the Tk manual regarding windows in canvas widgets:

> Note: due to restrictions in the ways that windows are managed, it is
>   not possible to draw other graphical items (such as lines and images)
>   on top of window items. A window item always obscures any graphics
>   that overlap it, regardless of their order in the display list.

Your solution could employ the use of canvas drawing elements which *can* overlay each other. I did not change the way the turn method works, but there is a leak there in the program. You should create the overlay elements once probably in **init**(), then you can raise, lower or move them around the canvas. But the turn method creates a new rectangle each time it is called.

```
from tkinter import *
import random

class game(Canvas):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        Canvas.__init__(self, parent)
        self.choices = ['Rock','Paper','Scissors']
        self.final_human_score = 0
        self.final_computer_score = 0
        font = ('TkTextFont', 12)
        rock_b = self.create_rectangle(50, 40, 120, 80, fill='black', tags='rock')
        rock_t = self.create_text(85, 60, text='Rock', fill='green', font=font, tags=('rock','trock'))
        paper_b = self.create_rectangle(150, 40, 220, 80, fill='black', tags='paper')
        paper_t = self.create_text(185, 60, text='Paper', fill='green', font=font, tags=('paper','tpaper'))
        scissors_b = self.create_rectangle(250, 40, 320, 80, fill='black', tags='scissors')
        scissors_t = self.create_text(285, 60, text='Scissors', fill='green', font=font, tags=('scissors','tscissors'))
        self.tag_bind('all', '<Enter>', self.activateElement)
        self.tag_bind('all', '<Leave>', self.deactivateElement)
        self.tag_bind('rock', '<Button-1>', self.rock)
        self.tag_bind('paper', '<Button-1>', self.paper)
        self.tag_bind('scissors', '<Button-1>', self.scissors)
        # Create the choice text elements
        self.choice_display = self.create_text(185,100,text="",fill="white",font=('Courier',13))
        self.c_choice_display = self.create_text(185,200,text="",fill="white",font=("Courier",13))
        self.human_turn = False
        self.computer_turn = True

    def activateElement(self, event):
        tag = self.gettags('current')[0]    # This returns rock, paper, or scissors
        text = self.find_withtag('t' + tag)[0]  # This returns the text element associated with the button
        self.itemconfigure(tag, fill='gray20')
        self.itemconfigure(text, fill='yellow')
        self.config(cursor="hand2")

    def deactivateElement(self, event):
        tag = self.gettags('current')[0]    # This returns rock, paper, or scissors
        text = self.find_withtag('t' + tag)[0]  # This returns the text element associated with the button
        self.itemconfigure(tag, fill='black')
        self.itemconfigure(text, fill='green')
        self.config(cursor="arrow")

    def turn(self):
        start_x = 75
        start_y = 100
        start_x2 = 90
        start_y2 =200
        Turn = self.create_rectangle(start_x,start_y,50,50,fill='green')
        not_turn = self.create_rectangle(start_x2,start_y2,50,50,fill='red')

    def rock(self, event):
        if self.human_turn == False:
            #280,90,400,113
            self.itemconfigure(self.choice_display, text='Rock')
            global human_turn #global required to change human_turn and commputer_turn
            global computer_turn
            self.human_turn = True
            self.computer_turn = False
            self.cc()

    def paper(self, event):
        if self.human_turn == False:
            self.itemconfigure(self.choice_display, text='Paper')
            global human_turn
            global computer_turn
            self.human_turn = True
            self.computer_turn = False
            self.cc()

    def scissors(self, event):
        if self.human_turn == False:
            self.itemconfigure(self.choice_display, text='Scissors')
            global human_turn
            global computer_turn
            self.human_turn = True
            self.computer_turn = False
            self.cc()

    def cc(self): #(computer choice)
        computer_choice = random.choice(self.choices)
        if self.computer_turn == False:
            if computer_choice == 'Rock':
                self.itemconfigure(self.choice_display, text='Rock')
                global human_turn
                global computer_turn
                self.human_turn = False
                self.computer_turn = True
            elif computer_choice == 'Paper':
                self.itemconfigure(self.choice_display, text='Paper')
                global human_turn
                global computer_turn
                self.human_turn = False
                self.computer_turn = True
            elif computer_choice == 'Scissors':
                self.itemconfigure(self.choice_display, text='Scissors')
                global human_turn
                global computer_turn
                self.human_turn = False
                self.computer_turn = True

root = Tk()
app = game(root)
app.pack()
root.mainloop()
```